# Python Fibonacci recursion (and not iteration) with O(n) time?

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

I know my simple version of a Python Fibonacci algorithm has a time complexity of O(2^n)^2:

```
def fibonacci_naive(n):
    if n < 0:
        return None
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 0
    if n == 2:
        return 1
    return fibonacci_naive(n - 1) + fibonacci_naive(n - 2)
```

I'm trying to write another Fibonacci recursion, but with O(n) complexity instead. So far I can think of the how to do this with a simple `for` loop but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how I can turn it into a recursive function instead. Any help is appreciated!

```
def fibonacci_fast(n):
    if n < 0:
        return None
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 0
    if n == 2:
        return 1
    fn_minus_2 = 0
    fn_minus_1 = 1
    for _ in range(2, n+1):
        temp = fn_minus_2 + fn_minus_1
        fn_minus_2 = fn_minus_1
        fn_minus_1 = temp
    return fn_minus_1
```

```
def fibonacci_fast(n, fn_minus_1=1, fn_minus_2=0):
    if n < 0:
        return None
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 0
    if n == 2:
        return 1
    return fibonacci_fast(???)
```

Comment: The Fibonacci sequence is one of the main examples why not to use recursion and think before implementing. The sequence is easily calculated by just adding the last two items together repeatedly, while some definition might lead you into a much more complex solution from the other direction, involving a fully grown tree of recursions.

Comment: I think you just can't. You could use memoizing to cache already calculated values and prevent recursion calls, but better don't use recursion at all.

Comment: @NobbyNobbs you definitely can, you have to use recursion as an iterative process

Comment: BTW the complexity is O(phi^n) IIRC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an *iterative process*, something like:

```
def fib_r(n, depth=2, minus_1=1, minus_2=0):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1

    elif depth < n:
        return fib_r(n=n, depth=depth+1, minus_1=minus_1 + minus_2, minus_2=minus_1)
    else:
        return minus_1 + minus_2
```

And just to show you, here it is compared to the version using iteration, basically, recursion acts as our loop:

```
In [1]: def fib(n):
   ...:     a, b = 0, 1
   ...:     for _ in range(n):
   ...:         a, b = b, a+b
   ...:     return a
   ...:

In [6]: def fibr(n, depth=2, a=1, b=0):
   ...:     if n == 0:
   ...:         return 0
   ...:     elif n == 1:
   ...:         return 1
   ...:     elif depth < n:
   ...:         return fibr(n=n, depth=depth+1, a=a+b, b=a)
   ...:     else:
   ...:         return a + b
   ...:
   ...:
    
In [3]: all(fib(i) == fibr(i) for i in range(1000))
Out[3]: True
```

So, everyone should read the [*Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs) by Ableson and Sussman.

Actually, MIT provides the PDF for free:

https://web.mit.edu/alexmv/6.037/sicp.pdf

Start reading section 1.2.1 about linear recursive processes versus iterative recursive processes (the efficient solution), and also, graph recursion (which is what the naive, inefficient solution uses).

Comment: Oh this makes sense! Is the acc=None parameter a mistake?

Comment: Also wouldn't it be possible to make n count down until it equals 2 rather than using depth? or would that not make sense...would it mess up minus_1 and minus_2?

Comment: oh yeah you're right, if we start from n and go backwards then we can't really use the defaults. Okay this works, thank you!

Comment: @idontknowanygoodusernames I've provided a link to a seminal textbook in computer science that explains this. The SCIP. It uses scheme, a dialect of LISP as a teaching language, which doesn't have loops, so you have to use recursion. It talks about linear recursive processes, iterative recursive processes (like the efficient recursive fibr), and tree recursion (the naive inefficient fib uses tree recursion). it actually talks about fibonnaci in section 1.2.2 and goes over both solutions!

Comment: @idontknowanygoodusernames and look at Alain T.'s solution for a version that counts down from N which is cleaner

Answer (score 5):

You can have defaulted parameters that move the sequence forward and use recursion to count down the number of elements:

```
def fibo(N,a=0,b=1): return fibo(N-1,b,a+b) if N else a
```

You can use the same approach to obtain the first N values of the sequence:

```
def fibo(N,a=0,b=1): return [a] + fibo(N-1,b,a+b) if N else []
```

Comment: ah this is much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can learn much more from this post:

[How to write the Fibonacci Sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence)

But I'll share a code anyway.

```
def fibonacci(n): 
      
    f = [0, 1] #first two nummber as 0, 1
     
    for i in range(2, n+1): #for i from range 2 to n+1
        f.append(f[i-1] + f[i-2])
    return f[n]
```

P/S: If I'm not mistaken, recursive fibonacci will always be O(2^n) / exponential